# My objective is to write a condition as If I click on 'Card 1' I need to populate value of arr2 which matches with common property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two array 'arr1' and 'arr2' . 
I displayed the Properties of 'arr1' via bootstrap Card(panels).
I have a common property on both the array .

My objective is to write a condition as If I click on 'Card 1' I need to populate value of arr2 which matches with common property.

```js
Eg: arr1 = [{'id':1 , 'tutorname':'Alpha'},
            {'id':2 , 'tutorname':'Beta'},
            {'id':3 , 'tutorname':'Gamma'}];

arr2 = [{'id':1 , 'student':'ajai','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'gopi','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'ganesh','age':20},
        {'id':1 , 'student':'nandha','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'Joshua','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'mohan','age':20}];
```

If I Click Alpha , Students Ajai,nandha  and their age should display
If I click Beta , Students Gopi,Joshua nd their age should display  res.
I'm able to display value based on 'id' in both array .

https://codepen.io/rnd-167/pen/bGGrGxq?editors=0110

Comment: Just filter the second array by id?

Comment: But I'm getting all the data from array 2, pls check the codepen link above

Answer (score 0):

```
    var arr1 = [{'id':1 , 'tutorname':'Alpha'},
            {'id':2 , 'tutorname':'Beta'},
            {'id':3 , 'tutorname':'Gamma'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':1 , 'student':'ajai','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'gopi','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'ganesh','age':20},
        {'id':1 , 'student':'nandha','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'Joshua','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'mohan','age':20}];

function click(tutorName) {
  const tutor = arr1.find((item) => item.tutorname === tutorName);
  const values = arr2.filter((item) => item.id === tutor.id);
  console.log(values);
}

click('Alpha')
```

Will display:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "student": "ajai",
    "age": 20
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "student": "nandha",
    "age": 20
  }
]
```

Comment: in Click Function If i call the dynamic Value , its not working                                                                       
                                                                                                 click('+arr1[i].tutorname+');

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/rnd-167/pen/vYYJzgK?editors=1010)

Comment: This should work:

$.each(arr1,function(i){
  var Xdata = '<button>'+arr1[i].tutorname+'</button>';
  $("#dis").append(Xdata).on( "click", function() {
  click(arr1[i].id)
  });
})

Comment: nope it's not working <br> I've Updated ur sol above pls have a look

Comment: For all the buttons id=1 value is populating @Nenad Borovčanin

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var arr1 = [{'id':1 , 'tutorname':'Alpha'},
            {'id':2 , 'tutorname':'Beta'},
            {'id':3 , 'tutorname':'Gamma'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':1 , 'student':'ajai','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'gopi','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'ganesh','age':20},
        {'id':1 , 'student':'nandha','age':20},
        {'id':2 , 'student':'Joshua','age':21},
        {'id':3 , 'student':'mohan','age':20}];



$.each(arr1,function(i){
  var Xdata = '<button>'+arr1[i].tutorname+'</button>';
  $("#dis").append(Xdata).on( "click", function() { click(arr1[i].id) });
})

function click(tutorID) {
  const tutor = arr1.find((item) => item.id === tutorID);
  arr2 = arr2.filter((item) => item.id === tutor.id);
   
   $.each(arr2,function(i){
  var Value = $('<p>'+arr2[i].student+'</p>');
  $('#stu').append(Value);
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dis">
  
</div>

<div id="stu"></div>
```

For Dynamic Call Its not working @Nena
Have a look at [Console Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEgr7.jpg)